# Is there a way to easily move between albums/artists when listening to music on iPhone/iPod touch

Tags: iphone, music

In the iPhone, whenever I select an artist or album to listen to, the play ends (or repeats) whenever the end of that artist or album is reached.  I would like a way for the music to continue to the next album/artist.

Or, what would accomplish the same purpose is if I could choose to play all songs, but sort songs by album and/or artist.

In other words, I would like to play my songs the same way I do on iTunes, in which I can simply play an album, and it will move to the next album or artist (depending on sort) after that current album is done.

I'm running iOS 6.

Comment: check your settings !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I have found to do this is to create a playlist on iTunes on my Mac and sync my iPhone with that Playlist.  If I sort by Artist in iTunes before syncing, it is synced that way on my iPhone.  I then scroll through the playlist on my phone to select an album or artist, instead of selecting the artist or album directly.  This way my music app will go to the next artist or album after my current album is finished.